# Wordpress File Upload Hook

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, hook

I am trying to hook into the Wordpress file uploader and would like some suggestions. I would like to be able to grab the path of the source file (not WP path; i.e. K:\docs\file.pdf) so I can download another file of the same name (different extension) & path automatically (i.e. K:\docs\file.txt).

Wordpress provides hooks for after the file is uploaded but all path information at that point is internal to wordpress.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

the path information can be obtained from normal php functions like [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [realpath(](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)) for example  .

Comment: You didn't read my question. I'm not looking for the path after the file is uploaded into wordpress. I'm looking for the path of the original source file.

Comment: you did not read my answer nor the functions listed there . they have got nothing to do with wordpress. this is how to check for path regardlsess of wordpress. this is how to get path of file in php . If you need something else please explain better (like where your original file is .. )

Comment: First of all I am not yapping. I am trying to help. You specifically asked for a not `WP path` and information which is not `internal to wordpress` . If you would like to elaborate and explain yourself better , please do so . there is a reason why no one else did not even try to answer your question. It is very unclear. I deal with uploading of wp images all the time , from server , from external URL , from network blogs or from Computer. But without some code or a better explanation of your need, no can guess what you really want . (at least not me)

Answer (score 0):

Bit too late to the party but I think what you are asking for is to find the source of the document in the clients system and based on that you want similar files there to be picked up by the browser and then sent to the user.

I think it will be a fairly complex thing to do, firstly you have to get the source of the document being added to the browser (I am not sure it can be done, but if it can be done then it will be via javascript) and then upload all the files one by one to the server hosting wordpress and you can do this by creating a custom page which will add the files uploaded to it as a wordpress attachment and then using something like jquery file uploader to upload files to that location.

But honestly, I think it would be a very complex thing, unless the client and the server are on the same machine.